# How to encode arbitrary amount of parameters for encodeWithSignature without adding them to function definition?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation, abi, bytes, encoding

Lets says we have `Contract A` that needs to call `Contract B` at a certain address which the requirements that `Contract A` doesn't know the exact parameter structure the function in that `Contract B` needs & assumes the user will provide the correct parameters.

So far I have the following.

```
function callExternalContractWithPacked(address _contract, address _testAddr) external {
        bytes memory arg = abi.encode(_testAddr);
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _contract.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setAddr(address)", arg)
        );
        emit Response(success, data);
}
```

While testing the `abi.encode` theory I passed a test address into the function & encoded it using `abi.encode` although there was a serious problem. Once the function ran & called the other contract, the address set on `Contract B` was completely different from the address added to the function before encoding.

How can I properly pass a argument of `bytes` into `abi.encodeWithSignature` without the data becoming corrupt & incorrect than the desired input.

During my search I came across [encodeFunctionCall :: Web3js](https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/4.x/packages/web3-eth-abi/src/api/functions_api.ts#L129) but would like the same result within solidity. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `abi.encode` with `abi.encodeWithSignature`, and encoding your address twice.

`abi.encode` takes your address and pads it with zeros to make it 32 bytes long since EVM works with 32 bytes slots only.

`abi.encodeWithSignature`, on the other hand, takes the signature of the function you're calling, along with its arguments, and encodes them too.

In your code, your encoded values look like this:

```
0xd1d80fdf
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4
```

The first line `0xd1d80fdf` is the function signature. The next three lines represent your double encoded values.

What you want is just:

```
0xd1d80fdf
0000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4
```

Your address follows the function signature, padded with zeros to fit 32 bytes.

To fix the issue, use only `abi.encodeWithSignature` to encode the function signature and address, don't use `abi.encode` before that.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense with the dual encoding bug, but how do I use `abi.encodeWithSignature` with an unknown amount of arguments so that it can work with a wide rang of different function calls?

Comment: Since `abi.encodeWithSignature` return `bytes memory` couldn't I just skip the encoding within the contract & encode outside the contract with the proper function definition & args & pass them directly into the `_contract.call()` statement?

Comment: You can encode the data to send without using `abi.encodeWithSignature`. 

All you have to do is first encode your values, but don't forget to put the signature of the function you're calling first `d1d80fdf`

Then `_contract.call(encodedValue)`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, how should I encode the values? How do I add the function hash to the encodedValues?

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how I get this `0x60fe47b100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ff` from outside of the contract into `_contract.call()`

Comment: Was able to figure it our using this `(bool success, bytes memory data) = _contract.call(_data)` where `_data` being an parameter of `bytes calldata` this way allowing me to encode everything on the client where I had a previous service written

Comment: You can do something like:

```bytes memory arg = abi.encode(_testAddr);
        return bytes.concat(bytes4(0xd1d80fdf), arg);```